# How to copy text from IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Is there a way to copy text out of Python IDLE on a Mac? When I highlight text and copy then past into a text editor, I get the same text pasted. It is some of the first text I start with in IDLE.  None of the other text will copy out.

Comment: Not really an answer, but the only positive thing I can say about IDLE is it's cross-platform. I'd recommend using a proper code editor, and Terminal or whatever feature is available in your editor to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Things I Hate About IDLE That I Wish Someone Would Fix](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2011/11/29/the-things-i-hate-about-idle-that-i-wish-someone-would-fix/) (from 2011):

> *1.2) NEW FEATURE: Auto-Copy-On-Highlight*
>
> Once we get rid of being able to move the cursor off the last line, that opens a new opportunity to implement an automatic copy-on-highlight feature that many terminal and IRC client programs implement. Since this text is read-only, the only reason a person has for highlighting it is to copy it (they can’t delete it.) As soon as the user highlights text in the shell window, it is copied to the clipboard.

Comment: No - it doesn't copy to the clipboard. have you tried it?

Comment: Does not work in IDLE with Python 2.7.10 on Windows. Does Mac work differently?

Comment: i dont own a mac so I cant verify that it works.  I just googled your issue and this looked promising

Comment: This idea in someone's blog post was never formally proposed as an enhancement on the bug tracker, and therefore never discussed, let alone implemented.

Comment: Then that makes sense then.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in things like a linux terminal you can't do a normal copy and paste, try holding `Command/Control + Shift + C` after highlighting things and seeing if that works, since you're on mac i'm not sure if it would be the Command or Control key so try both

EDIT: There is an [apple discussion about the exact same thing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5167269?start=0&tstart=0). They discuss going into the options menu, then into configuration and navigating to the keys section. Then you use a built in key-set, their suggestion is using IDLE Classic Mac.

Comment: are you in the IDLE editor or the console where you enter one line at a time?

Comment: The icon I click is called IDLE. But the window title is 'Python 3.5.1 Shell'.

Comment: I would also advise starting to use a new IDE. At first I wanted to stay inside IDLE as it was a familiar environment but trust me, switching over to Eclipse or Spyder (my current IDE) will help you out greatly in the long run

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best you can do is save as a .py file.  Open that in a text editor and continue working in IDLE.  With each save, the text editor will refresh with all updates, including errors.  At least TextWrangler will.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from your description exactly what you did and what happened.  But I can recommend that you upgrade to 3.4.4 or 3.5.1 (or 2.7.11 for 2.7 users).  Among other improvements, they all contain a patch to make right-click for context menu work on Mac Aqua.  This was [issue 24801](https://bugs.python.org/issue24801) on the CPython bug tracker.

If there is still an actual problem on Mac, I would like to know so it can be fixed.